# How to change say command to require a Channel ID and send the message there instead of where the command is sent?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Here's my current say command, I've only been fiddling with JS and Discord.JS for a few days so forgive me if this is a silly/easy fix.

````js
const { Util } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "say",
  ownerOnly: true,
  category: "owner",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    if (!args.length) return message.channel.send("No message provided");
    return message.channel.send(Util.cleanContent(args.join(" "), message));
  },
};```
````

Answer (score 1):

Use `GuildChannelManager#get()`

```
const specificChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('channel-id-here');
specificChannel.send('Hello World!');
```

Comment: That would let me do !say <channel ID> <message> and it would send it to that channel?

Comment: I provided the method for retrieving a channel object, you have to implement the rest